# set Context.User.identity:name to JavaScript variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to get the value of the user `@Html.Encode(Context.User.Identity.Name)` in a JS variable and set this value to an input with id= idAccion in order to send this value via jQuery to my controller in MVC C#, this is what I got so far but doesn´t work

```
function getPerson() {

@{
    var proveedor = @Html.Encode(Context.User.Identity.Name); 
}
   $("#idAccion").val(proveedor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ticks or quotes for a string and you do not need `@Html.Encode`.

```
function getPerson() {
    var proveedor = '@Context.User.Identity.Name';
    // rest of code
}
```

If you are expecting `'` as a value in the string you can escape them with a `.Replace` function on the string `Name` in the template.

```
var proveedor = '@Context.User.Identity.Name.Replace("'", @"\'")';
```